# How to batch export layers to KML in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, kml, batch

Is there a way to batch export layers to KML from ArcMap (ArcGIS Desktop) by altering the layer to KML tool to have more than one layer input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you right click the Layer To KML tool in the ArcToolbox, there is a batch option.  This is common for most of the geoprocessing tools for ArcGIS 10.  You could also use the Map To KML tool, which creates a kmz of all the layers loaded within a saved mxd.