# How to use arcpy.mapping to batch export layer to KML?

Tags: kml, layers, arcpy

I am trying to export map layers from an MXD to KML using arcpy with the following code:

```
import arcpy, os, sys, traceback

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Layer_KML\MXD\Test.mxd")

try:
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):
        i = 1 # forgive the wonky naming convention, I just wanted something quick for test purposes
        outKML = "C:\\Layer_KML\\KML\\" + "Test" + str(i) + ".kmz"

        # These lines are where the error/s is occuring
        newLayer = arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(lyr, "C:\\Layer_KML\\Layers\\" + str(lyr) + ".lyr")        
        arcpy.LayerToKML_conversion(newLayer, outKML, "20000", "false", "DEFAULT", "1024",     "96")

        i = i + 1

except:
        ...
```

Though my traceback keeps telling me : {ERROR 000623: Invalid value type for parameter in_layer.}  for both (I commented out each indivudally to test) the .SaveToLayerFile, and LayerToKML routines.  I am assuming these routines want to except a full file path, while the arcpy.ListLayer() only yields a basename.  Maybe?  I am really not sure.  Any thoughts as to why this isn't working?

I have already seen this question : [How to batch export layers to kml in Arcmap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15622/how-to-batch-export-layers-to-kml-in-arcmap) and this is not what I am looking for.  I want to do this in Python rather than through a toolbox tool.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to save to layer file, just do this:

```
import arcpy, os, sys, traceback

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Layer_KML\MXD\Test.mxd")

try:
    for i, lyr in enumerate(arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)):
        outKML = "C:\\Layer_KML\\KML\\" + "Test" + str(i + 1) + ".kmz"

        # These lines are where the error/s is occuring
        arcpy.LayerToKML_conversion(lyr, outKML, 20000, "false", "DEFAULT", "1024",     "96")
except:
        ...
```

Comment: I had tried this but it did not work.  I tried your code but my traceback still spews:  Error Info:
     <class 'arcgisscripting.ExecuteError'>: ERROR 000622: Failed to execute (Layer To KML). Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000623: Invalid value type for parameter layer.

Comment: In the documentation it looks like the arcpy.LayerToKML_conversion() is excepting a double for the scale parameter and you the code above seems to be passing a string. try this arcpy.LayerToKML_conversion(lyr, outKML, 20000, "false", "DEFAULT", "1024",     "96")

Comment: This works dango, thanks a bunch.  I knew it was something simple that I was overlooking.  Its odd, I still get the same error, but I actually get working KML's in my output folder.  However I think I narrowed down the problem.  It was trying to export an ESRI basemap as a KML as well (since I guess it is a layer in mxd).  I think the basemap kept causing the LayerToKML to fail.  I dont suppose either of you know of a way to add a conditional to my script that only gets a list of the layers that are visible(turned on)?  Thanks all.

Comment: maybe you could try something like this:

Comment: you already have the layer object "lyr" so all you need to do is add an something like this "if lyr.visible == True:". Hope that helps. Check out this if you want to read more on arcpy.mapping layers http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Alphabetical_list_of_arcpy_mapping_classes/00s30000000t000000/